# Text is jerky while javascript is loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've included a simple javascript into a site that requests data from another site.  When that code is present, the text in the header div jerks to the left and then to the center where it belongs while the site is loading.  This happens every time you press refresh in the browser.

I am not sure if my div layout or CSS are contributing to the problem.  I know that my code is not perfect, but I don't know if this problem is occurring because of it or in spite of it.

How can this be remedied?

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#hello {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#output {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/myip-jerktest.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="hello">
    <div id="logo">
      Text Logo Here
    </div>

    <span id="output">
  <script>
   function getIP(json) {
    document.write(json.ip);
   }
  </script>

  <script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP">
  </script>
 </span>

    <div style="width:400px;height:45px">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably because you're using... `document.write`

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the output to this output div, by

```
function getIP(json) {
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML=(json.ip);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#hello {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#output {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div id="hello">
    <div id="logo">
      Text Logo Here
    </div>

    <span id="output">
      
    </span>

    <div style="width:400px;height:45px">
    </div>
  </div>
      <script>
        function getIP(json) {
          document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = (json.ip);
        }
      </script>

      <script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP">
      </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I moved the script at end of the body try now

Comment: Tried it, does not fix the problem.

Comment: try now. moved script at body end

Comment: This seems to work on the main page.  The issue now is that on other pages the output will need to go both in the #output div and in several spans.  How would you write that up?

Comment: sorry didn't get you

Comment: On the page in the example, it's easy to redirect the javascript's output to the correct place because it's clearly named `id="output"`.  But what do you do on other pages where the javascript's output needs to go to #output AND to a bunch of different spans within different paragraphs?

Comment: If all your pages have same pattern say the first div and last span . `document.querySelector('body > div:first-child > span:last-child').innerHTML` or you could dedicate a span in all pages

Comment: Yes, I'll dedicate a span class to all spans that have the jquery output.  Can you help with the javascript that will cover both id=output and class=ouput-span?

Comment: if you give output as id than its a dedicated thing you just say `$('#output').html(json.ip)` all your pages will load mutually exclusive so there is no conflict

Comment: How can I assign multiple <span> elements the same ID?

Comment: You cant, you can use a class `<p class="yourthing"></p>` and to other elements `<span class="yourthing"></span>` and then `$('.yourthing').html(json.ip)` will put ip in all elements with classname `.yourthing`

Comment: I understand that.  But I still have the #output ID div in the header, in addition to that span class.

Comment: put this in every page `<span id="output"></span>` and `$('#output').html(json.ip)` should be enough

Comment: I thought we just established that it would be a class, not an id?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-writing the HTML document with `write`, append a new DOM element to the `body` of the document.

Also, I would create an `XMLHttpRequest` request object to retrieve the JSON data.

```js
loadJson('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.ipify.org?format=json', getIP);

function getIP(json) {
  let el = document.createElement('DIV');
  el.innerHTML = json.ip;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}

function loadJson(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = (e) => callback(xhr.response);
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  xhr.send();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#hello {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#output {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">
  <div id="logo">Text Logo Here</div>
  <span id="output"></span>
  <div style="width:400px;height:45px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the head of the document is fine. Or it can be placed down in the body.

Comment: The output still needs to go somewhere.  It goes in the #output div on the index page but will also need to go in other span classes on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
#hello {
    display: block; // or nothing at all as divs are block leveled as default
    text-align: center;
}
```

You should append the IP , on a paragraph, Rather than writing, Here it produces, span which is inline.
 if you want span to be centered then you should apply css rules to make it take full width, align center.

Answer (score 0):

use  `document.getElementById().innerHTML`

**Demo**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

#hello {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#output {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/myip-jerktest.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="hello">
    <div id="logo">
      Text Logo Here
    </div>
    <span id="output">
    </span>
    <div style="width:400px;height:45px">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    function getIP(json) {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = json.ip;
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```